# Given a JSON file , how do we display it as a tree with checkboxes

Tags: json, checkbox, treeview

And the provided JSON has different format i.e., without any ID's or state's mentioned
for example.,

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse it as a json, then you can loop through the array and create checkboxes.

```
<script>
var arr = $.parseJSON(jsonstring);
$.each(arr, function(i,v){
 $("div#yourDiv").append("<label name='"+i+"'>"+v+" <input type='checkbox' value='"+v+"' name='"+i+"' /></label>");
})
</script>
```

I haven't tested this, but you probably get the idea.